# Load list based on value json request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I ran into a little problem while doing this. Currently I have a script that loads the statelist on page load. Great right, its cascading with the countylist so whenever a state is changed it sends an ajax call to the server and then gets the countylist items into the countylist dropdown depending on the state. Now I want to do something a little different while keeping the same functionality. I want to be able to get the State and County on one-click #load. So once I hit load it will send an ajax call to the server and get a state and county name back that is tied to that load call. But here's there problem, I can change the statelist value to the state but then it doesnt change the countylist at all. The county list is completely null, so I have to open the statelist and click on the statelist to load the county list. I tried using on load, click, change ect. But it doesn't work so I am wondering if you can help me. Enough of me talking here is some code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $stateList = $("#StateList");

    $stateList.change(function () {

        var statelist = $stateList[0];
        var countylist = $("#CountyList");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "GetCounties",
            data: { "jsonString": statelist[statelist.selectedIndex].value },
            success: function (data)
            {
                countylist.html(data);
            },
        });
    });
        $("#Load").click(function () {
var orderdetailid = document.getElementById("LoadOrderDetailID");

    var statelist = $("#StateList");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "GetState",
            data: { "jsonOrderInt": orderdetailid.value },
            success: function (data) {
                {
                    statelist.val(data)
                }
            }
        });
        var orderdetailid = document.getElementById("LoadOrderDetailID");
        var countyname = $("#CountyList");
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "GetCountyName",
            data: { "jsonOrderInt": orderdetailid.value },
            success: function (data) {
                {
                    countyname.val(data)
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is a photo:
http://imgur.com/6RtxMSh

Comment: Please read [this essay](http://sscce.org) and consider editing your question.

Comment: @patstuart the words just explain what the code is doing so people have a better understanding. if you can read the code you do not have to read the writing. I also added a photo

Comment: It also has about 10 sentences, all but a few of which are redundant ("enough of me talking"). Regardless, I'm not trying to pile on, just let you know how to make sure people don't immediately ignore your post. Also, you either didn't copy and paste your code correctly, or you haven't correctly closed the function in the `$("#Load").click` statement.

Comment: You have almost repeated your last question! Why would you make 2 separate ajax calls instead of just return both values in 1 call? And why do you think the `countylist` would be populated. The only place you populate that in the `$stateList.change()` function.

Comment: And I suggest you rethink your `GetCounties()` method and return JSON containing the option values and text rather that trying to return html.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. I was missing parts of the code and thats why it didnt make any sense. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$("#Load").click()` function does not trigger populating the `CountyList`. It also seems unnecessary to call 2 ajax methods where your passing the same value. You could use a single call to a method that returns JSON containing all the data you want.

Script

```
$('#Load').click(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("GetOrderDetails")';
  var id = $('#LoadOrderDetailID').val();
  var stateList = $('#StateList');
  var countyList = $('#CountyList');
  $.getJSON(url, { ID: id }, function(data) {
    if(data.State != stateList.val()) {
      // need to repopulate counties
      countyList.empty();
      $.each(data.CountyList, function(index, item) {
        countyList.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
      });
      stateList.val(data.State);
    }
    countyList.val(data.County);
  });
});
```

Controller

```
public JsonResult GetOrderDetails(int ID)
{
  var state = // get the state value
  var county = // get the city value
  var countyList = // get the value and display text properties of counties
  // for example
  var countyList = db.Countys.Select(c => new
  {
    Value = c.ID,
    Text = c.Name
  }
  return Json(new { State = state, County = county, CountyList = countyList }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues here. 
1) .val() does not trigger change events, so your statelist.val(data) does not trigger your $statelist.change() this is by design, change events only trigger on user input. You can force the change by manually triggering it, i.e. your code becomes:

```html
statelist.val(data);
statelist.change();
```

this will resolve your immediate problem. 
2) Bigger issue is that you are running asynchronous code here and you are assuming it will run in some specific order. So once your problem is fixed by doing #1 above, you will still run into issues when one Ajax call finishes out of sequence (as they are bound to do) and thus you will have some instances where the line

countylist.html(data);

executes after the line:

countyname.val(data)

you really need to rethink your logic, as others said you do not need two separate calls for the county and value and the county list. Also you should explicitly make the second ajax call after the first returns (in the call back, or in the change event) so that your code is not executing in some random sequence.